# How to connect Web app to Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am trying to understand the Azure stack, still learning a lot. But i can't understand the logic behind the Azure Data Lake (gen2 storage account). I want to save forms from a website (created in PHP) as a json file in Data Lake.

I got the JSON file ready to upload but how can i upload this to Azure Data Lake? Or would i have to take a other route, Data Factory for example? I am trying to understand how someone would connect a external web application (created in PHP) to a Data Lake storage.

Also interested if it would be better to gather al the form data of one day and then push it to Data Lake instead of pushing each form separately.

I want to accomplish this:

```
Webpage --> Form posted --> Data Lake (Form data as Json file)
                        --> Local MySQL database (working already)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is and Data Lake Store SDK for your language available, you can simply use that to write files directly from your code. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-dotnet#upload-a-file-to-a-directory) for an example for C#.

Since there is currently no SDK for PHP, the alternative is to use the [Blob Storage SDK for PHP](https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-php). Since it is still the same storage, you can upload the file using the blob interface and still access it using the Data Lake interface.

Comment: Thank you, do know if its a common way to store each form data as a seperate JSON file or do i bundle the forms of one day and push it to the data lake each night?

Comment: sure, you can store single files there. The question is really what you want to do with them later? if you want to query them individually, maybe something like a document store such as Cosmos DB might make more sense?

Comment: I have multiple incoming messages from different sources (web apps). I want to use the data lake as a storage for all the forms and do some transformations before it is send to one SQL server. So all the different forms and fields can be transformed into one final SQL database. Never used Cosmos DB, i will look into it. Thank you